# sorting files according to keywords, need a more database-y solution

Tags: sorting, batch-file, batch-processing

I'm making a script that sorts video files into folders by checking for known keywords in the file. As the amount of keywords grows out of control the script becomes very slow, taking several seconds for each file to be processed.

```
@echo off    
cd /d d:\videos\shorts
if /i not "%cd%"=="d:\videos\shorts" echo invalid shorts dir. && exit /b

:: auto detect folder name via anchor file
for /r %%i in (*spirit*science*chakras*) do set conspiracies=%%~dpi
if not exist "%conspiracies%" echo conscpiracies dir missing. && pause && exit /b
for /r %%i in (*modeselektor*evil*) do set musicvideos=%%~dpi
if not exist "%musicvideos%" echo musicvideos dir missing. && pause && exit /b

for %%s in (*) do set "file=%%~nxs" & set "full=%%s" & call :count
for %%v in (*) do echo can't sort "%%~nv"
exit /b

:count
set oldfile="%file%"
set newfile=%oldfile:&=and%
if not %oldfile%==%newfile% ren "%full%" %newfile%

set count=0
set words= & rem
echo "%~n1" | findstr /i /c:"music" >nul && set words=%words%, music&& set /a count+=1
echo "%~n1" | findstr /i /c:"official video" >nul && set words=%words%, official video&& set /a count+=2
set words=%words:has, =has %
set words=%words: , =%
if not %count%==0 echo "%file%" has "%words%" %count%p for music videos
set musicvideoscount=%count%

set count=0
set words= & rem
echo "%~n1" | findstr /i /c:"misinform" >nul && set words=%words%, misinform&& set /a count+=1
echo "%~n1" | findstr /i /c:"antikythera" >nul && set words=%words%, antikythera&& set /a count+=2
set words=%words:has, =has %
set words=%words: , =%
if not %count%==0 echo "%file%" has "%words%" %count%p for conspiracies
set conspiraciescount=%count%

set wanted=3
set winner=none

:loop
:: count points and set winner (in case of tie lowest in this list wins, sort accordingly)
if %conspiraciescount%==%wanted% set winner=%conspiracies%
if %musicvideoscount%==%wanted% set winner=%musicvideos%
set /a wanted+=1
if not %wanted%==15 goto loop

if not "%winner%"=="none" move "%full%" "%winner%" >nul && echo "%winner%%file%" && echo.
```

Notice the "weight value" for each keyword. It counts the total points for each category, finds the largest value and moves the file to the folder appointed to that category. It also displays the words it has found and lastly lists files it finds unsortable so I can add keywords or tweak weight values.

I have stripped the amount of folders and keywords in this sample to bare minimum. The full script has six folders and 64k size with all the keywords (and growing).

Comment: If you want it in PowerShell, you'd need to do some basic code yourself first, and *if you have a problem* return here with a specific question about what's not working.  From what I can see, your primary issue with the existing batch code is it's performance, is that right?

Comment: I understand. That's right, performance. I suspect this is the prime example of the wrong way of doing things. The only actual problem I am having is with special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "tempfile=%temp%\somename"
SET "categories=music conspiracies"
REM SET "categories=conspiracies music"
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=," %%s IN (q45196316.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*%%u*" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
   ECHO %%a^|%%s^|%%t
 )
)
)>"%tempfile%"

SET "lastname="

FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=|" %%a IN ('sort "%tempfile%"') DO (
 CALL :resolve %%b %%c "%%a"
)
:: and the last entry...
CALL :resolve dummy 0 

GOTO :EOF

:resolve
IF "%~3" equ "%lastname%" GOTO accum
:: report and reset accumulators
IF NOT DEFINED lastname GOTO RESET
SET "winner="
SET /a maxfound=0
FOR %%v IN (%categories%) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=$=" %%w IN ('set $%%v') DO CALL :compare %%w %%x
)
IF DEFINED winner ECHO %winner% %lastname:&=and%
:RESET
FOR %%v IN (%categories%) DO SET /a $%%v=0
SET "lastname=%~3"
:accum
SET /a $%1+=%2

GOTO :eof

:compare
IF %2 lss %maxfound% GOTO :EOF 
IF %2 gtr %maxfound% GOTO setwinner
:: equal scores use categories to determine
IF DEFINED winner GOTO :eof
:Setwinner
SET "winner=%1"
SET maxfound=%2
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q45196316.txt` containing this category data for my testing.

```
music,6,music
music,8,Official video
conspiracies,3,misinform
conspiracies,6,antikythera
missing,0,not appearing in this directory
```

I believe your problem is that repeatedly executing `findstr` is time-consuming.

This approach uses a data file containing lines of `category,weight,mask`. The `categories` variable contains a list of the categories in order of preference (for when the score is equal)

Read the data file, assigning category to `%%s`, weight to `%%t` and mask to `%%u` and then do a directory-scan using the mask. This will `echo` a line to the tempfile in the format `name|category|weight` for each name-match found. `dir` seems to be very fast after the first scan.

The resultant tempfile will thus have one line for each filename+category plus the weight, so if a filename fits into more than one category, more than one entry will be created.

We then scan a sorted version of that file and resolve the score.

First, if the filename changes, we can report on the last filename. This is done by comparing the values in the variables `$categoryname`. Since these are scanned in the order `%categories%` then the first category in the list is chosen if there is an equivalence of scores. The scores are then reset and `lastname` initialised to the new filename.

We then accumulate the score into `$categoryname`

So - I believe that will be a bit faster.

---

Revision

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "tempfile=%temp%\somename"
SET "categories="rock music" music conspiracies"
REM SET "categories=conspiracies music"
:: set up sorting categories
SET "sortingcategories="
FOR %%a IN (%categories%) DO SET "sortingcategories=!sortingcategories!,%%~a"
SET "sortingcategories=%sortingcategories: =_%"
:: Create "tempfile" containing lines of name|sortingcategory|weight
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims=," %%s IN (q45196316.txt) DO (
 SET "sortingcategory=%%s"
 SET "sortingcategory=!sortingcategory: =_!"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*%%u*" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
   ECHO %%a^|!sortingcategory!^|%%t^|%%s^|%%u
 )
)
)>"%tempfile%"

SET "lastname="

SORT "%tempfile%">"%tempfile%.s"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2,3delims=|" %%a IN ("%tempfile%.s") DO (

 CALL :resolve %%b %%c "%%a"
)
:: and the last entry...
CALL :resolve dummy 0 

GOTO :EOF
:: resolve by totalling weights (%2) in sortingcategories (%1) 
:: for each name (%3)
:resolve
IF "%~3" equ "%lastname%" GOTO accum
:: report and reset accumulators
IF NOT DEFINED lastname GOTO RESET
SET "winner=none"
SET /a maxfound=0
FOR %%v IN (%sortingcategories%) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=$=" %%w IN ('set $%%v') DO IF %%x gtr !maxfound! (SET "winner=%%v"&SET /a maxfound=%%x)
)
ECHO %winner:_= % %lastname:&=and%
:RESET
FOR %%v IN (%sortingcategories%) DO SET /a $%%v=0
SET "lastname=%~3"
:accum
SET /a $%1+=%2

GOTO :eof
```

I've added a few significant comments.

You can now have spaces in category names - you need to quote the name (for reporting purposes) within the `set catagories...` statement.

`sortingcategories` is automatically derived - it's only used for sorting and is simply the categories with any space in a name replaced by an underscore.

In creating the tempfile, the category is processed to contain underscores (the sortingcategory) and when the final placement is resolved, the underscores are removed returning the category name.

Negative weights should now be processed appropriately.

-- further revision for "not append *"

```
 FOR /f "tokens=1-5delims=," %%s IN (q45196316.txt) DO (
 SET "sortingcategory=%%s"
 SET "sortingcategory=!sortingcategory: =_!"
 FOR %%z IN ("!sortingcategory!") DO (
  SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion
  FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
   'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%~v%%u%%~w" 2^>nul'
```

AND

add 2 extra columns to the q45196316 file

```
music,6,music,*,*
music,8,Official video,"",*
conspiracies,3,misinform,*,*
conspiracies,6,kythera,*anti,*
missing,0,not appearing in this directory,*,*
rock music,2,metal,*,*
conspiracies,-5,negative,*,*
```

The `for /f ... %%s` now generates `%%v` and `%%w` containing the last two columns (as `tokens` is nor `1-5`)

These are applied as prefix and suffix to `%%u` in the `dir` command. Note that `""` should be used for *nothing* as two successive `,` are parsed as a single separator. The `~` before the `v`/`w` in `%%~v` means `remove the quotes`.

Comment: I am taking my sweet time understanding the code. It works well but I wish it had the possibility to have a category name with spaces in it. I tried using `"music videos"` instead of `music` but it didn't work (probably obvious). I don't understand the code well enough to do much editing at this point...

Comment: I notices I can use the `?` as a wildcard within the database file. very nice! I wish I could use a negative weight value too, it would be helpful when sorting the difficult stuff. right now using a negative value puts the file into the first category.

Comment: Oh my, that looks like a near complete rewrite. I owe you a serious dept of gratitude so thank you! That being said I could trouble you for one last thing; could add echo for what keywords were found? I'm not sure I could even do that myself. I must admit I'm more that a bit confused trying to decode this.

Comment: The only changes were to use `sortingcategory` instead of `category` AFAIR. Now what do you mean by the keywords found?

Comment: See sometimes when a file gets misplaced it seemingly makes no sense because you can't imagine what relevant word was matched. That's why my script displays the hits for each file. It often turns out the weirdest filings happen when a short word is matched because its part of a different, longer word. So having the matching words displayed (preferably on a single line) is great for building up the database properly.

Comment: Easy-fixed. I've changed the revised code in a minor way. First, I added new columns to the tempfile being generated (%%s=category and %%u=matched string). Then moved the sorting out of the `for/f` command and created a new sorted tempfile with `.s` appended to the name. Then change the `for /f` command by including the name of the sorted file, adding the `usebackq` option (so that a quoted filename can be used) and changing the `tokens` to `1,2,3` as there's now more data on the line. Take a look at the ".s" tempfile.

Comment: I was thinking echoing something like `"how and why jackass is so popular.mp4" has jackass (3) for entertainment (3 total) + how (2), why (2) for useful tidbits (4 total)` to the prompt but I do need this proper logging too, I will change it into a cumulative log. I tried building this `echo` sentence but I don't quite understand your variables. For example where do you get the variables `%%t`, `%%u`, `%%b`, `%%c` and `%%x` since I don't see them declared right after a `FOR` command anywhere? I'm thinking these are created using `tokens` but how are these letters picked without declaring?

Comment: Where you have a `tokens` option in a `for/f`, each text line is "tokenised" - seen as a series of character-sequences ("tokens") separated by delimiter-sequences (as specified by the `delims` option - a set of characters to use as delimiters). The lowest token number in the `tokens` option is assigned to `%%s` where `s` is the metavariable (loop-control variable), the next lowest to `%%t` (the next alphabetically) and so on. `*` means "the rest of the line after highest-selected token" and is assigned to the next %%? - see `for /?|more` from the prompt for details

Comment: Seriously, `Take a look at the ".s" tempfile.` - it should contain all you need.

Comment: OK I get it. I need one more tweak for this. I need it to take no action unless a file has at least two points total.

Comment: Initialising `maxfound` to `1` instead of `0` in the `:resolve` routine should ensure that a file with fewer than 2 points (ie. 1 or fewer) will be assigned to `winner = none` since then a score of <=1 will fail the `gtr` test which changes the value of `winner`.

Comment: this code is so f****** awesome. I just had to go back to this revision to fix all my accumulated problems with it. BTW which bit do I change if I want to NOT have `*` wildcards automatically added to the search? I want to control the beginning and ending wildcards for each keyword/mask.